# (IB / TWS) How to see price chart of different exchange places for the same stocks?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, interactive-brokers

I am quite new on this field and I have an account on InteractiveBrokers in order to trade stocks. Problem is, some stocks are listed in multiple exchanges (for example on SBF - France - but also in XETRA - Germany). When I open the price chart on TWS (happens the same on the other platforms as well) it only shows the price chart for the main stock exchange. Example:

- If I open the price charts for BMW, which is originally traded by XETRA, then it will show me the XETRA prices only.
- If I open the price charts for CARREFOUR S.A., then it will show me the prices of the SBF, which is where it is originally traded.

However, those stocks are also listed on other exchanges. Even though the price is similar, is there a way to visualize prices in other exchanges through the software? I know that IB offers the Smart Routing mechanism, which looks for the best price for a stock and chooses smartly the best exchange. But that applies only when making the order, not when visualizing the stock information. Does anyone know if it's possible to explicitly open the price/information charts on a specific exchange place, as well as placing the buy/sell order only on that exchange (i.e. ignoring Smart routing completely for both buying/selling and visualizing)?